# Kivy MD how to use multiple ScreenManagers

Tags: kivy, kivymd

For the purpose of having multiple Screens for App startup (without BottomAppBar) and later after sucessful login having multiple Screens with BottomAppBar I tried to solve this by initializing two ScreenManagers in the *.kv File.

See below the structure of the *.kv file.
Question: How can I handle the ScreenManagers ('sm' and 'ssm') from the *.py File?
Current status:  'sm' appears and works as usual
Target status: 'ssm' should appear at start up; after sucessful login sm should appear

Thank you for any help!

```
MDScreen:   

    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        ScreenManager:
            id:ssm

            LoginScreen:

            SignupScreen:
  
    MDNavigationLayout:    
        x: toolbar.height    
        size_hint_y: 1    
        #size_hint_y: 1.0 - toolbar.height/root.height

        ScreenManager: 
            id: sm
            #LoginScreen: 
            #SignupScreen: 
            GraphScreen:   
            ActionScreen:  
            Screen:   
                name: "scr5"   
                MDLabel:  
                    text: "Screen"  
                    halign: "center"   


        MDNavigationDrawer:    
            id: nav_drawer        

            ContentNavigationDrawer:    
                screen_manager: sm    
                nav_drawer: nav_drawer    

    MDTopAppBar:    
        id: toolbar    
        type:"top"    
        title: ""    
        left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state("open")]]
    
    MDIconButton:    
        icon:"images/final_me.png"    
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .8,'center_y': .05}    
        icon_size: "60sp"
```

Comment: I apologize for ruining your post. I attempted to improve the formatting and accidentally deleted your kv code and cannot figure out how to restore it. Would you please edit your post and add the kv code again. Again, I apologize for my error.

Comment: I think that I restored your code correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can define your initial `Screen` as you have done in your `kv` as:

```
MDScreen:   

    BoxLayout:
        id: box
        ScreenManager:
            id:ssm

            LoginScreen:

            SignupScreen:
```

with `id` added to the `BoxLayout` for easy access.

Elsewhere in your `kv` you can define what you refer to as `sm` using a custom class and a rule in in your `kv`. The custom class can be something like:

```
class SM(ScreenManager):
    pass
```

And a rule in the `kv` to define how the `SM` class should be built:

```
<SM>:
    GraphScreen:   
    ActionScreen:  
    Screen:   
        name: "scr5"   
        MDLabel:  
            text: "Screen"  
            halign: "center"
```

Now, if your `LoginScreen` includes a `Button` that calls a `login()` method in your `App`, then you can remove the `ssm` from the `BoxLayout` and replace it with an instance of the new `SM` class. Something like this:

```
def login(self):
    self.root.ids.box.remove_widget(self.root.ids.ssm)
    self.root.ids.box.add_widget(SM())
```